# Force template method in non-template class

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, virtual

I try to achieve the following behavior/syntax/usage of this class:

```
Data1 dataType1;
Data2 dataType2;

int intType;
float floatType;

dataType1.method( intType );
dataType1.method( floatType );

dataType2.method( intType );
dataType2.method( floatType );
```

My approach would be this:

```
struct CDataBase
{
    template< typename T > virtual void method( T type ) = 0;
};

struct CData1 : CDataBase
{
    template< typename T > void method( T type ) {}
};

struct CData2 : CDataBase
{
    template< typename T > void method( T type ) {}
};
```

However virtual template methods aren't possible. Also there is no need for an actual base class, However I have to ensure that some classes got a (template) 'method()' implemented.

How do I force a non-templated class/struct to override a template method?

---

EDIT: 
This is my actual layout:

```
struct Data0
{
    int someVar;

    template< class T >
    void decode( T& type )
    {
        type.set( someVar );
    }
};
```

EDIT:
in the current version of C++ (11) the behavoir I try to achieve isn't possible. In addition to that, I should really recode this part to avoid this problem. However I accept the only answer given, thanks for you affort.

Comment: _How do I force a non-templated class/struct to override a template method?_ You might want to use a [static type check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722493/c-template-metaprogramming-static-type-checking).

Comment: First, :%s/how/why/g What problem are you trying to solve? Virtual and template *members* don't mix (which you've discovered). I concur with @πάνταῥεῖ. Perhaps a trait model will better suit your end-goal.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm still looking for the (outdated) link to a paper showing a concise way, how to setup concept checks for pre-c++11 standards. I've based a  little concept check framework based upon this, may be I should post it as a github gist or project. I'm currently not that familiar what's possible with the [tag:c++11] standard [type support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) going into this direction.

Comment: If I could I would mark it as duplicate to this one I just found on the related menu: [how-to-design-around-the-limitation-that-templated-member-functions-cant-be-vir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592424/how-to-design-around-the-limitation-that-templated-member-functions-cant-be-vir). Double Dispatch or global functions are a solution to this, but I didn't lost my hope for the (easy) usage I actually want.

Comment: @Serthy Yes, this also would answer your question, as long you're insisting for the need of pure virtual functions.

Comment: Yes, I should add this to my question. There is no need to derive from a base class, I just have to ensure that some other classes define a (templated) 'method()'.

Comment: I forgot I already published the static check framework on github :), [it's already there](https://github.com/makulik/StaticInterfaces)! I hope this might solve some of the problems pointed out in your question strategically. The earlier you check for a particular interface given from a template type, the clearer the resulting compiler message tends to be humanly readable. That's all of the basic approach!

Comment: In the code you've posted, there's no need to use a template method... you can overload member functions with the same name by declaring them with different parameters.  Or, if your `decode` function will always call `type.set()`, you can make all the T's derive from TBase and use this signature: `void decode(TBase& type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea to check for specific functions implemented of a given template parameter type, is to try instantiate function pointers of these. The compiler will complain, if the function pointer initializations cannot be resolved.

Here's some sample code to illustrate the principle:

```
template<typename T>
void check_has_foo_function() {
    void (T::*check)(int, double) = &T::foo;
    (void)check;
}

struct A {
    void foo(int, double) {};
};

struct B {
    void bar(int, double) {};
};

template<typename CheckedClass>
struct Client {
    void doSomething() {
        check_has_foo_function<CheckedClass>();
        CheckedClass x;
        x.foo(5,3.1415);
    }
};

int main() {

    Client<A> clientA;
    clientA.doSomething();

    // Uncomment the following lines to see the compilation fails
    // Client<B> clientB;
    // clientB.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Note the call to the `check_has_foo_function<CheckedClass>();` function will be completely optimized out, and doesn't have any impact on runtime performance.

Based upon this, further abstractions could be provided (e.g. to generate checks using preprocessor macros). I have published a [little experimental framework](https://github.com/makulik/StaticInterfaces) on GitHub that uses these techniques.