# How the has_trivial_default_constructor works?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++03

Can somebody explain me how `has_trivial_default_constructor` works? I tried to find it in a boost implementation but unfortunately there are too many macros and I just got lost...

How somebody can detect the `trivial_default_constructor` in C++ using templates?

I need an example in C++ 03 not 11.

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

  struct A{
    A(){}
    int a;
    //std::vector< int > b;
  };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  struct B{
    std::vector< int > b;
  };


  bool result =  boost::has_trivial_default_constructor<A>::value;

  //std::forward(&test);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ AlexTheo: it's not necessarily the case that Boost has a *working* C++03 implementation of the function. i remember that some of those type inspection functions just had dummy implementations, because they couldn't be implemented even with compiler sniffing and use of compiler-specific features. perhaps you can **check whether the Boost implementation works**, and post results of that?

Comment: May be my answer to this recent question gives you some pointers (pun intended): [Force template method in non-template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132500/force-template-method-in-non-template-class?noredirect=1#comment33581855_22132500)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: one cannot obtain a pointer to a constructor, since constructors do not have names, so, i don't see how the answer applies?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thats right otherwise the answer would be quite simple use sfinae and check for the function (stl does it for a find all the time )

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Hmmm, yes. I had doubt's about exactly this point, after posting this comment. Even more interesting question though!

Comment: Have you looked into the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_trivial_constructor.html)? "Without some (as yet unspecified) help from the compiler, `has_trivial_constructor` will never report that a user-defined class or struct has a trivial constructor" The implementation w/o compiler support to me seems to be based upon `is_scalar`, i.e. if it's a fundamental type (integer, enum, ..).

Comment: The intrinsics used to implement `has_trivial_constructor`, or rather `BOOST_HAS_TRIVIAL_CONSTRUCTOR`, can be found in `boost/type_traits/intrinsics.hpp`

Comment: @dyp you almost have an answer already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's impossible (in pure C++).

Detecting whether a type has a default constructor is possible with SFINAE because it only involves the *interface*, but detecting whether it's trivial involves the *implementation*.

Therefore, a compiler **must** provide a specific intrinsic for this. You can find a list of intrinsics [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checks-for-type-trait-primitives), note that some are provided because they require a compiler intervention and others may be provided just to have a uniform set or streamline the Standard Library implementation.

The particular intrinsic you are looking for is either `__has_trivial_constructor` which is also supported by gcc and MSVC according to the comments or `__is_trivially_constructible` (Clang's specific). I must admit being slightly unsure of the former (what if the type has several constructors ?), the latter can be used as:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_trivial_default_constructor {
    static bool const value = __is_trivially_constructible(T);
};
```