# Calling convention in function_traits

Tags: c++, function, boost, type-traits

I am now writing wrappers for some library calls on Windows. For each function, I need to extract its prototype and re-apply them in the wrapper, for example the wrapper for the recv function:

```
int recv(SOCKET, char*, int, int);
```

could be

```
int recv_wrapper(SOCKET, char*, int, int, <additional params>);
```

Since the extraction is erroneous, I try to use the boost function_traits to get the parameters of the original function, like that:

```
typedef boost::function_traits<decltype(recv)> recv_traits;
recv_traits::result_type recv_wrapper(recv_traits::arg1_type, ...);
```

But that doesn't work because `decltype(recv)` is a function pointer, so I modify it as:

```
typedef decltype(recv) ptr_recv_t;
typedef boost::remove_pointer<ptr_recv_t> recv_t;
typedef boost::function_traits<recv_t> recv_traits;
```

But it still does not work because the recv is translated (somewhere in the Winsock2.h) automatically as:

> int (__stdcall*)(SOCKET, char*, int, int)

AFAIK what I need is `int (*)(SOCKET, char*, int, int)` or `int(SOCKET, char*, int, int)`.

Many thanks for any consideration

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for, but for checking _'function traits'_ this might help: [Force template method in non-template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132500/force-template-method-in-non-template-class/22134647#22134647) (sorry the posts title doesn't much resemble yours here).

Comment: Thanks a lot πάντα ῥεῖ, though I cannot see the common between that question and my question. What I ask here is how can I get the prototype without the calling convention, i.e. int(SOCKET, char*, int, int) for the function recv.

Comment: My link just shows a way, to check those calling conventions you mention at compile time. If you have some class/function that matches the signature you want, the checks should pass, otherwise you'll get a compile-time error.